# ffmpeg android image and audio merging not woring

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg for making video(mp4) of image.jpg and audio.mp3.i used `-y,-i,%s,-i,%s,-shortest,-acodec,copy,-vcodec,mjpeg,-shortest,%s` this as command its run well but in output  getting only 1 frame. my audio file length is 3min and getting output of 1 sec.I refere [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1041816/combine-one-image-one-audio-file-to-make-one-video-using-ffmpeg) as well but not getting desire output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `-loop 1` input option before `-i image.jpg`.